# Get similar objects of same type from django taggit

Tags: django, django-taggit

I am using `django-taggit` tags in two models, lets say `Model1` and `Model2`. I am using below code to get similar objects from my one of the model.

```
obj1 = Model1.objects.get(pk=1)
similar = obj1.tags.similar_objects()
```

In the similar objects I am getting `Model2` objects also. So How to get only `Model1` similar objects.

Answer (score 2):

By default `django-taggit` uses a “through model” with a `GenericForeignKey` on it, that has another `ForeignKey` to an included Tag model. However, there are some cases where this isn’t desirable, for example if you want the speed and referential guarantees of a real ForeignKey, if you have a model with a non-integer primary key, or if you want to store additional data about a tag, such as whether it is official. In these cases `django-taggit` makes it easy to substitute your own through model, or `Tag` model. [see docs](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html)

Suppose we have a `Food` model.Сreate a through model, in the same place as your Model

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase


class TaggedFood(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey('Food', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Food(models.Model):
    # ... fields here

    tags = TaggableManager(through=TaggedFood)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Food

def food(request, pk):
    food = get_object_or_404(Food, pk=pk)
    similar_foods = food.tags.similar_objects()[:5]
    context = {
        'food':food,
        'similar_foods':similar_foods
    return render(request, 'food.html', context)
```

**food.html**

```
{{ food.field }}
{% for food in similar_foods %}
    {{ food.field }}
{% endfor %}
```

So the `queryset` will be executed only on the `Food` model. Do the same for the other model if necessary.